# C for Confusion? Order of declaration causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Not sure why the order of `go` matters in this simple loop which is inside my `main` function:

```
int go = 1;
int choice;
char *n;

while(go){
    printf("1: insert letter into tree\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("enter letter: ");
        scanf("%s", n);
        printf("%s\n", n);
    }
}
```

I get a segmentation fault. But when I write it like this,

```
int choice;
char *n;
int go = 1;

while(go){
    printf("1: insert letter into tree\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("enter letter: ");
        scanf("%s", n);
        printf("%s\n", n);
    }
}
```

with `go` at the bottom, it works as expected. I usually define variables like `go` globally anyway, but I'd appreciate any insight as to why this happens inside the main function.

Comment: Both versions are broken. It's pure fluke that one of them did what you wanted.

Comment: The `scanf` function reads into memory that must already exist , it does not allocate memory

Comment: Where does `n` point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have here is **undefined behavior** because you are reading into a `char*` without allocating memory for it.

```
char *n; //no memory allocated.

scanf("%s", n); //reading into n here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither version allocates memory for `n` and so you have undefined behavior.

To avoid using dynamically allocated memory you can do something like:

```
char n[32]; /* pick a number bigger than the strings you expect */
scanf("%s", n);
```

Or use `malloc` to get some memory

```
char* n = malloc(32);
```

Both ways will have problems if you enter more characters that the allocated memory allows for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that n does not have memory allocated. So when you read and assign a value in n and go is declared after it, it is overwriting the content of go. When you access go, it generates seg fault.

If you move it upwards, it is still doing OOB write but do not know where. However go is not touched and it works.